# I have "unknown PCI device" in Windows 7 device manager. What can it be?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, lenovo-laptop, device-manager

I have just performed a fresh installation of Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit on my lenovo e330 laptop. I managed to successfully download and install most of its drivers, but still, a "PCI Device" appears under "other devices" in the device manager.

What could it be? How can I check what is missing?

Answer (score 8):

When you have unknown hardware which is 20 years or less old you usually can get the PCI device ID. This will help you indentify which hardware it is, rather than a generic *PCI Simple Communication Controller* or similar.

For unix like OS'ses such as FreeBSd, Linux or OS X use `lspci` or `pciconf`.

For windows you can use the hardware ID tab in the device manager.

To start the device manager either go to [start] [run] and type `devmgmt.msc` or right click on the [my computer] icon on your desktop, select "manage" and click on the device manager option.

(Screenshots from win 7. It is similar in XP).

[image: Starting the device manager via start run devmgmt.msc]

[image: Starting the device manager via my computer and manage]

From device manager:

- Go to the device you want to find the hardware ID from.
- Right click on it and select "properties".
- Go to the tab "Details" and change "Device description" to "Hardware ID".

[image: Image of the harware IDs in the device management screen]

Note the value with the lines like this one: `PCI\ven1002&dev_6898&subsyst_0b`...

Search for that in the internet or use a site like http://www.pcidatabase.com/.

Note that these IDs have a fixed format. The first number will always indicate the manufacturer. In the demonstrated case in the screenshots that is ATI/AMD (ATI was bought out by AMD).

[image]

The remaining numbers indicate all the details, often down to the revision number.

Comment: Value is "PCI Device" :) @Hennes

Comment: @Alex post a screen shot then

Comment: @Alex switch from hardware id to instance id.  Take the value before _x and match it to the pnp devnode tree.  That should at least tell you what kind of device it is and where its located on your system.  +1 to Hennes for an excellent answer.

Comment: pcidatabase.com is a dead website now.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20170916222435/http://pcidatabase.com/  Has a snapshot of it from 2017-09.  Seems to work. Will look for a better modern alternative.

Comment: I've been using https://pcilookup.com/

Comment: There is also https://devicehunt.com .

Answer (score 2):

Go into proporties/details under the pci device in question and google for the value (don't google for the whole string though) for example, my Network controller has the value:

> "PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&subsys_e000145&REV_06

if I google for

> "ven_10EC dev_8168"

Then the top google results gives me a good indication what the drivers are for. (then I just google for the official site of the hardware to get the drivers)

Comment: Value is "PCI Device" :) @Curs3d

Comment: under "Hardware ID" ?, please include a screenshot then, because I really have no clue how that could happen :/

Answer (score 1):

Interesting how this is still very much a current issue when upgrading Lenovo laptops to Windows 10, where no media card reader driver is loaded/installed by Windows.  At this time (August 2015) when Windows 10 was just released, Lenovo had no Windows 10 driver available, although the previous Windows 8.1 version works fine. I downloaded and installed it manually.  Search "Realtek Media Card Reader Driver" on Lenovo's website.

Answer (score 0):

I can bet that this is the Realtek PCIE Card Reader :) I've seen the same issue with lenovo Think Pad Edge users more than once, and it's always the Realtek Card reader driver :)

Try with this Win 7 Lenovo drivers [Realtek Media Card Reader-RTS5229](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/h3sd07ww.exe)