# No network configuration after clean install of Windows 7 Professional 32 bit on Dell Inspiron 6410

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, dell-inspiron

I just installed a new hard drive and used the Dell provided Win7 media to clean install Windows 7 professional 32 bit on my Dell 6410 Inspiron. After it is installed there is no network of any kind and it did not give the option to enable it (no IEEE, no wireless,etc).  The BIOS reads normally and all devices are active. However, it appears that no drivers are available on the 3 drivers disks provided either.

Two questions.

1. Why wouldn't Win7 Pro autoconfigure the network during setup?
2. Any thoughts on workarounds?

Comment: Device Manager? are there any network adapters there? if unknown, then install the driver. Drivers are usually on the other cd/dvds if those cd/dvds are for your make & model...otherwise download the drivers from another computer. One Dell dvd contains the OS, the 2nd usually has the drivers and the 3rd dvd has 3rd party applications.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is sometimes possible for setup, but actually in my experience it more often isn't - since third parties use different, non-standard drivers, and particularly for wireless cards Windows cannot automatically configure them.
2. You can download [all the drivers for your laptop here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/Product/inspiron-6400x) directly from Dell. Just select Vista (32-bit) from the drop down, click on Network, and then choose the *Dell Wireless ... WLAN Driver*, unless when you bought it you upgraded to the *Intel PRO* wireless option, in which case select that download.

You can also download the BlueTooth, Ethernet, and other drivers there if you so wish, but once you have an internet connection set up, Windows Update should happily install everything else for you.

Despite it saying Vista, they should be fine for Windows 7 even without running in compatibility mode.

**To run in compatibility mode:**

- Right click > Properties > Compatibility
- Select the tick box *'Run in compatibility mode for'*
- Choose Vista
- Hit *OK*, then run the installer by doing right click > Run as Administrator

Comment: Thanks Ollie.  I have a Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 Wi-Fi installed, but there doesn't appear to be a driver for it on the Dell DVDs.  Any idea of an alternate?

Comment: [Here's the download page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23045&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%207%20(32-bit)*&DownloadType=Software%20Applications) - choose the top one (Ds stands for Drivers and software).

Answer (score 1):

1. Becuase they could not find the drivers.
2. Install the driver. Drivers are usually on the other cd/dvds if those cd/dvds are for your make & model...otherwise download the drivers from another computer.

One Dell dvd contains the OS, the 2nd usually has the drivers and the 3rd dvd has 3rd party applications.

Comment: Thanks, but the drivers are not on any of the three DVDs. Lots for vista and XP, nothing for Win7.

Comment: All you need is the network adapter driver, you will have to download that driver from another computer and transfer the driver to your computer (dvd/usb drive) like Mattias Åslundmentions. That install dvd(s) was not for your particular model.... though Win7 can use Vista drivers.

Answer (score 0):

On Dell website you can type the servicetag of your computer and get all relevant drivers for it

Comment: Cool. How does that answer the questions at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

> Why wouldn't Win7 Pro autoconfigure the network during setup?

Because this is only possible if windows recognises the devices and has drivers for it. If you have reasonably modern hardware, a relative old OS or some more exotic device then you have to supply the drivers yourself.

This is usually done by downloading them and copying them to an USB pedrive **before** you format.

> Any thoughts on workarounds?

Identify which devices you have. Either by checking the PCI-e HW IDs (as described in a few [posts](https://superuser.com/questions/657879/i-have-unknown-pci-device-in-windows-7-device-manager-what-can-it-be) here on [su], or by using the servicetag on [Dell's website](http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1). Then download the drivers.

Obviously you need to do that from another PC, but since youwere able to post I assume you have another device with Internet access.